# Trying to click div and fire off function in a class everytime it is clicked...says TypeError in console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking at how to use classes to create objects in Javascript and wanted to create a class with a function inside that I could use once a div is clicked...However, every time I click the div I get TypeError

I have google search answers and see results with a button in html solution, but I want to do this using javascript only.

I have tried using
document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function(event) {Bucket.selectAndFill(event)};

but it says that selectAndFill is not a function in the console.

```js
let buckets = [];
class Bucket {
  constructor(Content, SelectStatus) {

    this.content = Content;
    this.selectStatus = SelectStatus;

  }
  selectAndFill() {

    for (let bucket of buckets) {

      this.content = "i changed it";

    }

  }
}


for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  buckets[i] = new Bucket("empty", false);
  console.log(buckets[i]);
}


//this line was my attempt but it says that selectAndFill is not a function in the console        
document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function() {
  Bucket.selectAndFill()
};
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `static` keyword next to the method.

```js
let buckets = [];
class Bucket {
  constructor(Content, SelectStatus) {
    this.content = Content;
    this.selectStatus = SelectStatus;
  }
  static selectAndFill() {

    for (let bucket of buckets) {
      this.content = "i changed it";
    }
    console.log(buckets);
  }
}


for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  buckets[i] = new Bucket("empty", false);
  console.log(buckets[i]);
}
   
document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function() {
  Bucket.selectAndFill();
};
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `function` from `Class` modifying the call this way:

```
const bucketFill = new Bucket;
document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = bucketFill.selectAndFill;
```

Comment: functioms from class are not static in javascript